Nginx gives 403 Forbidden error serving files
I am a newbie to nginx and run into a problem: nginx response with 403 Forbidden when I request example.com/media/ and all files inside the media folder. I am creating   web application with python using Django Rest Framework.
Here is my nginx file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:
server {
    server_name example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log;
    
    location /media/ {
        alias /root/spaceai/backend/SpaceAI_Backend/apps/media/;
    }

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 0;
        gzip off;
        ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
        ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
        proxy_read_timeout      300;
        proxy_connect_timeout   300;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;

    }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

Here is media folder rights: drwxr-xr-x 3 755 root 4096 May
Head of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

I can not solve this problem for the day and would be very grateful for help.
